# Is it safe to make ApplicationDbContext public? ASP.Net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Actually you can't directly make ApplicationDbContext public, but you can make some tricks like here https://codedocu.com/Net-Framework/ASP_dot_Net-Core/Data-Model/Asp_dot_Net-Core_colon_-How-to-get-the-ApplicationDbContext-in-an-Asp_dot_Net-Core-MVC-application?2221

So the question is, is that safe to make ApplicationDbContext context public, do you get any vulnerabilities by this way?

Comment: Access modifier are for hiding things from the `Developer` to prevent coding errors.  If a hacker has access to your ddls you have already been hacked

Comment: @johnny5 thank you, so making ApplicationDbContext context public threatens only with developer's mistakes? And if hacker has access to my ddls, access modifier doesn't make a difference? Did I get it right? You can copy-paste your answer bellow, I'll mark it like an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a few clarifications, there are some cases in which it could cause a vulnerability e.g MVC Controllers but for the most part you should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access Modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) are mostly used for the developer to prevent breaking internal workings.   You may make a variable private,  this shouldn't be consider a vulnerability

There may be a few case where an access modifier may cause a vulnerability, such as exposing a method on a controller in MVC(which will open that method up to the world).

But for the most part access modifiers are used by someone who already has access to your code

If someone has access to the inner workings of dlls, they can use reflection to change whatever values they would like.